# Getting the derivatives of Legendre polynomials in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I have an expression for a gravitational potential (eq. 15 from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3094)), and to calculate an orbit I need to evaluate the gravitational force which is the local gradient, and for me that means evaluating the derivative of the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Additional_properties_of_Legendre_polynomials) P2, P4 and P6 at single values tens of thousands of times.

[image]

I can calculate it using the expression in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/391672/284619), but I'm wondering if there is a way to ask python for the derivative that doesn't explicitly involve me evaluating the derivative as a finite difference.

I couldn't find anything in SciPy to do this automatically. In `numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre` there is a `deriv()` method but I have no experience operating with polynomial classes.

What would be the fastest way to evaluate the first derivatives of low order Legendre polynomials, one value at a time suitably for numerical integration?

Comment: You can try the `sympy` module, which, if I'm not mistaken, is a part of SciPy. It allows you to do really easy differentiation and integration, etc, but you'll need to deal with that infinite sum first, maybe SymPy can handle it as well as it's pretty good at evaluating limits and that kind of stuff.

Comment: @ForceBru thanks I don't think `sympy` is right for the job here. I can do the symbolic part myself - the answer is right there in the linked question. What I need is the fast numerical evaluation, and `sympy` does not do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am aware that this is an old question but still there is no answer on how to calculate the derivatives using numpy/scipy.

This is how it works with numpy and scipy only:

```
from scipy.special import legendre
import numpy as np
n = 2               # degree of Legendre polynomial
poly = legendre(n)  # coefficients of n^th degree Legendre polynomial 
polyd= poly.deriv() # coefficients of derivative of n^th degree Legendre Polynomial
x = np.linspace(0,1,10000)  # arbitrary coordinates
evald = np.polyval(polyd,x) # evaluate derivative at desired coordinates(s)
```

Also the accepted answer above contains a small mistake (I am not able to comment yet maybe someone can edit the answer):
The derivative should read `P2' = 3*x`

Comment: `+1` one more vote and you'll be able to comment :-) Thanks for your answer! Yes this is an old problem but I still [struggle with the algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/547131/83380) from time to time as well as the Python, what a coincidence I was just working on this general topic again!

Comment: fyi at some point early on you'll be able to edit other people's posts to make corrections, and the edits will to into a review queue. As long as they are appropriate they are usually accepted either by the post author or by others reviewing edits. It may take a day or so sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the derivatives of `P2`, `P4` and `P6`, that's easy enough to compute by hand and then write down as code... e.g.

```
P2 = .5 * (3 * x^2 - 1)
```

Therefore:

```
P2' = .75 * x
```

And you can write that in python as:

```
def P2_deriv(x):
    return .75 * x
```

Things don't really get a whole lot faster than that ;-).  If you need arbitrary legendre polynomials, well ... Things start to get a bit trickier at that point ...

Comment: OK since I've mentioned I only need a few low order polynomials, your are right. I can stop thinking of them as exotic objects that need special methods and just put pencil to paper. Thank you for bringing me back to Earth - spending too much time "in orbit around Saturn" rots the brain! :)